# PDO SQLSRV Execute command intermittently slow for same query

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a PDO connection to a SQL Server running two very simple scripts on the same connection.
When I run this on my local database I get a response back in around 10-50ms
If I run this on a database on the network I get a response back in anything from 1700 - 5000 sometimes longer. That is a complete connect, execute and fetch.

I have put in some debugging and have found that creating the connection is lightning quick  taking 1.5-1.6ms which is about 8 times slower than locally which is 0.25.
The bind is taking roughly the same on both servers HOWEVER the execute command is taking ages to complete, there seems to be no consistency at all.
The fetch statement is also lightning quick 0.15ms on average

The first query which is a select only returns in say 500ms the second which is an insert statement returns in 600ms.

The next time I run it the timings are reversed.

So I'm pretty confident that the problem is not with initial connection and not the statement itself - the fetch time is fine too which leaves the actual EXECUTE command.

I have tried several options in the PREPARE statement (such as CURSOR_FWDONLY) but this makes no difference at all.

I was initially thinking this is a network issue but as the connection is created quickly and the fetch takes no time at all I am now not sure what to do next.

```
$pdo = new PDO("SQL connect string", "username", "password");

$sql = "SELECT  top 1 col1,col2,col3 FROM your_table";

// Set cursor type to scrollable
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL]);

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// Move the cursor to the first row
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST);

// Fetch data
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Process each row
    print_r($row);
}
```

The above is a simple example - the issue I have is with the time it takes to perform the execute command.  The connection, the prepare, and the fetch are almost instant.
On my local machine that code would execute in 20-30ms but on my remote server the execute is taking up to 4500ms.
I would have thought that if it was a network speed the connect and fetch operations would be hit more than the execute itself.

Comment: Also do you have parameters that change each time you are calling the code?  This could effect the query plan (make it faster/slower depending on the parameters you are passing).

Comment: thanks guys - ive changed the initial question to include some sample code. Don't get bogged down with the SQL - Im also sending a parameter in mine but have tested with just a simple select and the same issue occurs.
I am really trying to work out if its the SQL box, the network or some issue with PDO itself.

Comment: Do you realize that MySQL is not the same thing as Microsoft SQL Server? You have used the `sql-server` tag for Microsoft SQL Server, and your PDO connection string is using `mysql:...`.

Comment: My bad - the connect string was wrong in sample code, ive changed it. 
Its to a Microsoft SQL Server box. The question is why the execute takes so long? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has problems with this, it seems that in our case a WMI process  was some how monitoring traffic and was effectively causing the CPU to run at 100% every time a pdo execute was called.
Process was identified using process explorer.